# How enable an disable linkbuttons style and events with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a linkbutton that shows a confirm window function when it's pressed:

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
     var continue = confirm('¿CONTINUE?');
    if (continue) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
});
```

I want to disable a linkbutton, its style and its clic event, when page loads:

```
 $('#LinkButton1').attr("disabled", "disabled").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
 });
```

The linkbutton is disabled and onclic server event is removed but the prompt it's still showing.

When user types something into a textbox this linbutton should be enabled again and get the previously unbinded clic events:

```
 $(':input').keypress(function () {
    $('#LinkButton1').removeProp('disabled').off('click');
});
```

This gets back the server onclic event but I now I miss the confirm windows.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tvbg9/3/
In this demo the confirm windows is not showed but i still see in my page.

What I am doing wrong?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only allow the clic event if any key is pressed onto any textbox:

```
$('#LinkButton1').attr("disabled", "disabled").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

$(':input').keypress(function () {
    $('#LinkButton1')
    .removeProp('disabled')
    .off('click')
    .click(function () {
         var continue = confirm('¿CONTINUE?');
         if (continue) {
           return true;
         }
         else
           return false;
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
        $('#LinkButton1').attr("disabled","")
```

you can try this

```
    $('#LinkButton1').removeAttr("disabled")
```

Hope it should work

Comment: You should use removeProp('disabled') instead

Comment: @Roasted: no, you *shouldn't* (the docs for [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) *explicitly* warn against this *unless* you want to *permanently* remove the property. Assuming that it can become `disabled` again, you should simply use `.prop('disabled', false)` to un-set the `disabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for disabling the button

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function() { return false; });
```

Then for the input:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        $('#LinkButton1').unbind('click');
});​
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When input changes I need to bind again the click event, not unbind it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tvbg9/

```
$('#LinkButton1').on('click',function(e){e.preventDefault()});

    $(':input').keypress(function () {
        $('#LinkButton1').off('click');
    });​
```

Comment: I edited your fiddle because i need to remove the confirm window also. And when click is binded again I miss the confirm window.
http://jsfiddle.net/Tvbg9/3/